# Does someone know an ios graphviz viewer library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, graphviz

I'd like, for an iPhone app, to show some tree-graphs (like UML graphs) to the user, and a good way to do that could be to have / write a [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) viewer. Has somebody heard about an existing iOS library doing this? The excellent [Instaviz app](http://instaviz.com/) shows that it's possible.

Thank you in advance for any clue

Comment: Maybe too late, but [this](https://www.accusoft.com/resources/blog/using-static-library-ios-app/) might help! (Disclaimer: I haven't tried it..)

Answer (score 0):

Graphviz generates its output as an image in one of [several formats](http://www.graphviz.org/content/output-formats).

You just have to find a format compatible with [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer; of course, it could be a solution (generate the graph on the server, and transfer it as an image), but in my case I would like to transfer only the DOT file, and create the graph on the iPhone... That's why I'm looking for a simple DOT viewer in Objective-C.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't need a server: embed graphviz in your iPhone app for converting the dot file to png or whatever.

Comment: To be clear, this application has a server part -- but that's not the subject: I misunderstood your suggestion the first time, do you know how to _embed_ graphviz in the iPhone app? I know I can virtually embed any C or C++ code in an Objective-C project, but I've never done it... Maybe you have a link to share with me? Thanks again.